# filter out "reversed" duplicated tuples from a list in Python

Tags: python

I've a list like this:

```
[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), ('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'A'), 
 ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'), ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')]
```

And with many more similar tuples, here the two first items are just the IP addresses in the opposite order.

Now, I need to create a new list which is unique on the combination
of the 2 first IP addresses in each tuple.

That is, for my purpose `('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A')` is the same as `('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'A')` , it doesn't matter which of those 2 I end up with. Though none of those would be the same as `('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'B')`

Given the list at the start, I need to end up with a new list:

```
    [('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'A'), ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'), 
     ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'A')]
```

What's an elegant way of doing this in python ?

Comment: See my comment under Abhijit's solution. Does it matter if `('192.168.9.1', '192.168.1.1', 'B')` gets converted to `('192.168.1.1', '192.168.9.1', 'B')` even if the second form does not occur in the input at all?

Comment: I think you have a one character typo. `('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'A')` should be `('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')` on the second-to-last line.

Comment: @ltn100 No, 'A' is perfectly valid and could occur in for that combination. The last element is only unique per pair of IP addresses.

Comment: @user1255770 Perhaps I'm missing something. How does the tuple `('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'A')` end up in your final list, given that it doesn't exist (in any order) in your initial list?

Comment: @ltn100  Someone edited my post for some unknown reason, originally there was ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'A') there instead of ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward, yet inefficient (`O(n²)`) approach (thanks, @Rafał Dowgird!):

```
>>> uniq=[]
>>> for i in l:                           # O(n), n being the size of l
...     if not (i in uniq or tuple([i[1], i[0], i[2]]) in uniq): # O(n)
...             uniq.append(i)                                   # O(1)
... 
>>> uniq
[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), 
 ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'), 
 ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')]
```

A more efficient approach using Python's `Set`:

```
>>> uniq=set()
>>> for i in l: # O(n), n=|l|
...     if not (i in uniq or tuple([i[1], i[0], i[2]]) in uniq): # O(1)-Hashtable
...             uniq.add(i)
... 
>>> list(uniq)
[('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C'), 
 ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), 
 ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B')]
```

You can sort it according to the last element:

```
>>> sorted(list(uniq), key=lambda i:i[2])
[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), 
 ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'), 
 ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')]
```

Comment: Ouch, this has O(n^2) complexity due to the linear test for membership in the `uniq` list.

Comment: Correct, but it's clear and the difference is minor for short lists. I'll revise it with sets, any how.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L=[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), ('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'A'), 
...  ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'), ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')]
>>> set(tuple(sorted((a,b))+[c]) for a,b,c in L)
set([('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.104', 'C'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), ('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.103', 'B')])
```

Comment: And you can wrap the whole thing in `list()` to get a list.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this would be as follows

```
>>> somelist=[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), ('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'A'), 
 ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'), ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')]
>>> list(set((y,x,z) if x > y else (x,y,z) for (x,y,z) in somelist))
[('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.104', 'C'), ('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'), ('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.103', 'B')]
>>>
```

Assuming the difference is because of the order of the IP addresses which are the first two item, create a generator and feed it to a set comprehension such that the IP address in the tuples are always in order. Then from the set create a list.

Considering Rafel's comment here is one another solution which preserves the order of a non-duplicate tuple

```
>>> someset=set()
>>> [someset.add(e)  for e in somelist if (e not in someset and e[0:2][::-1]+e[2:] not in someset)]
>>> list(someset)
```

The reason I am using a set in the above solution to make the membership operation faster

Comment: One caveat: OP only stated that it doesn't matter which one of the 2 equivalent tuples end up in the result, if there are indeed 2 equivalent ones. This solution might convert a tuple to its equivalent form even if the other form does not occur in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Group by normalized (i.e. addresses sorted) values, return original ones:

```
data = [('192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', 'A'),
  ('192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.100', 'A'),
  ('192.168.1.103', '192.168.1.101', 'B'),
  ('192.168.1.104', '192.168.1.100', 'C')]
normalized = dict([(min(t[0], t[1]), max(t[0], t[1]), t[2]), t]
                  for t in data)
result = normalized.values()
```